# Angular parent scope not updated when directive updates the same scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written a directive to validate certain binded value and modify it before executing the action on the button. But any value update in directive value is not reflected in the parent scope. I have used (=) in the directive so my assumption is it will update the parent scope as well.

Let me know what I am doing wrong. Have attached the images.

[image: This is the view where both parent and the directive sharing the same text value.]

[image: The result value assigned to the validate text is not reflected in the parent selected node. while the ok function is executed. I have tried $timeout, $evalAsync on the scope.ngClick with no success.][image]

This is the view where both parent and the directive sharing the same text value.

The result value assigned to the validate text is not reflected in the parent selected node. while the ok function is executed.

I do see the value getting updated back in the text area. But dont know why it is not updated when the ok funciton is executed.

I have tried $timeout, $evalAsync on the scope.ngClick with no success.

Comment: Why do you call `scope.ngClick()` inside your directive? It is called automatically by Angular's `ngClick` directive.

Comment: You see a $dialog that is an dialog box and only on clik on yes I will trigger the ngClick otherwise I should not allow the original ngClick to fire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes that are made inside event handlers of elements of custom directives are not triggering Angular's digest cycle. Therefore you need to notify Angular that scope has been changed (by calling `scope.$digest()` or `scope.$apply()`). Another thing I have noticed is that method `ok()` is called twice: once inside Angular's `ngClick` directive and second time inside your directive. If it is not a desired behavior, remove it from your directive. Here is some working code:

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="myController">
  <textarea ng-model="selected.note"></textarea>
  <button type="button" validatetext="selected.note" ng-click="ok()">Click Me!</button>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('online-desktop', []).
  controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.selected = {
      note: 'old value'
    };
    $scope.ok = function() {
      alert($scope.selected.note);
    };
  }]).
  directive('validatetext', [function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        validatetext: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        element.on('click', function() {
          scope.$apply(function() { // <= change scope properties inside scope.$apply()
            scope.validatetext = 'some new value';
          });
        });
      }
    }
  }]);
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/rmJVBzjIeiVcoQUV79z2?p=preview

Comment: @user2045685 Can you create some Plunker/JSFiddle/JSBin or whatever with your code, where I can see the error (digest already in progress)?

Comment: It worked the problem for me was. I used dialog service which called scope.$apply internally. So I have changed the code this way to work

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try a $rootScope.$broadcast from the directive and catch it in the parent with $scope.$on

```
//directive
$rootScope.$broadcast("valueUpdated", result);

//parent
$scope.$on("valueUpdated", function(event, result){
//update the value here
});
```

You can also probably use $scope.$emit instead of $rootScope.$broadcast.

Comment: I have multiple places to update, if that is the case I can instead write the utility function in the respective ok. I just want to create independent.

Comment: I have updated the question. I do get the updated value on the text area. The issue is it is not getting updated before the ngclick is triggered.